# How to improve search speed in elasticsearch (my main query: term query and phrase query)?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have about 165G data and I stored it into three elasticsearch servers(each server has 32G memory). The total size of the resulting index(named `my_index`) is 240.3GB (198030346 docs) with about 75GB used for indexes. The index `my_index` has three primary shards and no replica shards.

The index `my_index` has two fields(names `field1` and `field2`) with a same analyzer. The analyzer split content of `field1` and `field2` by space. A document looks like

```
{
  "field1": "AW110 AW111 AW112 AW113 AW1104 AW1103 AW11023 AW11012 AW1101 AW1102 AW1102 AW1101 AW11032 AW110 AW11032 AW11032",
  "field2": "BP111 BP111 BP111 BP111 BP111 BP1110 BP111s BP111s BP111a BP111as BP1117 BP1119 BP11100 BP11100 BP11100 BP11111 BP111009 BP11122"
}
```

My main query is `term` query and `phrase query`. For example, I want to search for all documents containing the term `AW111` or search for all documents containing the phrase `AW110 AW111`.

I have tried to improve search speed:

1. I configured `swapping`.

   - `vm.swappiness` is set to `1`.
   - make the user **hjs** who install **elasticsearch** can raise the locked memory size without limit.

```
hjs soft memlock unlimited
hjs hard memlock unlimited
```

```
- Enable `bootstrap.memory_lockedit` (set `bootstrap.memory_lock: true` in elasticsearch.yml)
```

Other configuration

- File Descriptors(/etc/security/limits.conf)

```
hjs soft nofile 65536
hjs hard nofile 65536
```

- JVM(config/jvm.options )

```
-Xms5g
-Xmx5g
```

- Virtual memoryedit(/etc/sysctl.conf)

```
vm.max_map_count=655360
```

This is a picture show the result of the command `top` when I running multiple `term search`. The process `31283` is **elasticsearch**.

[image]

The picture is used to show the cluster status:

[image]

**My question:** 
When I execute `term query` to search for documents that contain a specific terms, probably a large number of documents match the term. So when I search for a lot of terms(usually 10,000-40,000 and I used `multi search` + `term query`), it needs to cost too much time
is there any respect to improve search speed?

Comment: your shards are quite big. I would increase jvm heap size. mappings could help identify what could be done in terms of optimization

Comment: @AndreyBorisko What is the function of  jvm heap size? I have never understood the role of setting jvm, can you explain?

Comment: @Andrey Borisko When I  execute some search query, the heap usage is  less than half full

Comment: that's quite a broad topic to discuss but you can read what is recommended for ES there https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html